# Hibernate Inheritance and Polymorphism - Cascade actual Object, not the ParentClass

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

So I have an Entity B2, which has a list of Entities B with a OneToMany Relationship. At runtime, instances of the Entitiy B2 class either hold a List of Entities B1 or B2, where B1 and B2 are extending Entity B and have different Attributes. If I persist Entity B2, everything is cascaded, but the Entities B1 and B2 are persisted as B Entities and lose their properties, how can I prevent this and instead persist the actual objects, not just their parent representation?

Consider the following example:

Entity B:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
public class B {
//IDs, getters, setters and other irrelevant attributes

  @ManyToOne
  private parentB2;
}
```

Entity B1:

```
@Entity
public class B1 extends B {
//getters, setters and other irrelevant attributes

  // I don't want to lose this!
  @Embedded
  private Something specialAttribute;
}
```

Entity B2:

```
@Entity
private class B2 extends B {
//getters, setters and other irrelevant attributes

  //This could be B1 or B2
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
  List<B> childs;
}
```

Now I would add create an instance of B2, add two instances of B2 as childs to the first B2 and for the two childs I would give each 3 instances of B1 with special attributes. I want to be able to persist the parent and therefore the first B2 which has no parents itself, persist it and when I fetch it from my repository, I want that 6 instances of B1 still have their specialAttribute which they had when they were persisted. I really don't want one seperate list for B1 and B2 in the B2 class and implementing something like B2_Node and B2_Leaf would lead to the same problem where a B2_Node could have either B2_Nodes as childs or B2_Leaves and B2 Leaves would have a property which is seperate from B2_Nodes (the list of B1 Entities) which would therefore get lost again.

Comment: I understand the duplicate `@OneToMany` is a typo. That being said, you do realize that you've created **two** separate associations and not a single, bidirectional one, right? If you want a single, bidirectional association, you need `mappedBy` with `@OneToMany`. Also, how do you verify that `B2`s are actually getting stored as `B1`s? What are the values of the discriminator column?

Comment: Just note that if you're trying to verify the behavior by setting `B1.specialAttribute` to a new, empty `Something` and, after reloading the entity, the `B1.specialAttribute` is gone, that's how embeddables work. An empty embeddable is indistinguishable from an embeddable filled with default values, as far as JPA is concerned.

Comment: I don't need to verify whether or not a B2 has a list of B1s or a list of B2s, I will call a method on the B2 which the B class provides, the idea is to cascade a calculation from the bottom to the top so from the leaves to the root. I know that B1.specialAttribute would be gone if the entity is reloaded but I'am not reloading the entity, I only save it. After saving the root, I would fetch the root and call some method "calculate" on it, which lives inside the B class, every B2 calculates wiht the result of the calculation of it's children, B1 uses B1.specialAttribute for this, which is lost.

Comment: Well, if you're fetching the root in another transaction, you're fetching the entities from the db, in which case `Something` *will* most likely be `null` - unless you're referring to a case in which you have set some of the fields contained in `Something` to non-default values. In that case, plase post the mapping of `Something`, along with the method in which you're using it.